# Is there any way to use the SAP Fiori tools for creating SAP Fiori Application based on SAPUI5 version 1.38

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I need to create a Fiori App with Smart Templates using SAPUI5 version 1.38. My issue is that the version 1.38 has a Long-Term Maintenance status and there are systems that are still using that version, but the current version of SAP Fiori tools supports 1.65.0 as a minimal version.

- Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code as a development environment?
- Must I use SAP Web IDE or it is possible developing using some old SAPUI5 Tools version for Eclipse?
- Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Which tools do you exactly mean by "Fiori tools"? Do you mean the VS Code extensions? Could you provide a link that talks about the "Fiori tools" supporting only 1.65.0 and onwards?

Comment: Correct, I mean a set of extensions for VS Code. The Fiori Application Generator on the Project Attributes step has got a Minimum SAPUI5 version field. The 1.65.0 version is the last in the dropdown list.

Comment: The article [SAP Fiori tools 2202 release bring new features and makes troubleshooting easier](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/02/17/sap-fiori-tools-2202-release-bring-new-features-and-makes-troubleshooting-easier/) says "It will first check the UI5 version of the backend system and use that as the default." My backend system has got 1.38 but after the project is created the SAPUI5 version is 1.98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fullstack WebIDE does have the option for the 1.38 UI5 Version. So you could use it. And i think you can use any other ide like vb if the generator for the templates does have the version or you just create it by your own. Also you can import your 1.38 project in your current ide this also should work.

[image]

Comment: I used to develop Fiori Apps with VS Code. Additionally I've checked [SAP Development Tools](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5) page that says "SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse are no longer updated and no longer available for download." It seems there is only one approach for creation a Smart Template Project (SAP Elements) in SAPUI5 1.38 version is using Web IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Web ide personal edition

You could update ui5 libraries

Answer (score 0):

Ashley Tung has shared a link [on the SAP blogs site](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/02/17/sap-fiori-tools-2202-release-bring-new-features-and-makes-troubleshooting-easier/comment-page-1/#comment-612172) with a workaround from [SAP Application Generator help](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_FIORI_tools/42532dbd1ebb434a80506113970f96e9/160b4d8c680c463daf20c7399e2dc6ad.html#loio160b4d8c680c463daf20c7399e2dc6ad__app_generator_7):

### Issue

> When the user attempts to generate a SAPUI5 application from the template in SAP Business Application Studio, versions below 1.65 are not available from the drop-down list.

### Workaround

> Currently, SAP Fiori tools support SAP Fiori elements and SAPUI5 freestyle projects with minimum SAPUI5 versions 1.65 or higher.
>
> In case there’s a need to test an existing projects with a lower
> SAPUI5 version, the following workaround can be used to preview the
> application:
>
> 1. In the ui5.yaml file, manually set the SAPUI5 version to the needed one, such as 1.38.50.
> 2. In the HTML files, manually remove the “sap.f” references as they aren’t available in 1.38.50.
> 3. Additionally, update the theme `data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"` to a theme supported by the required version, such as 1.38.50:
>    `data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"`